# If EJB exposed @Remote interface, but you inject the EJB bean instead of its Remote interface, will this trigger a remote or local invocation?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I have a EJB bean that exposed to two interface like below: Local interface is for my web app, and Remote interface is for my App Client

```
@Stateless
public class CoreMainEJB implements CoreMainEJBRemote, CoreMainEJBLocal {
    //...
}
```

so my App Client looks as below. Remote method invocation is happened in this case

```
public class Main {
   @EJB
   private static CoreMainEJBRemote coreEJBRemote;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        coreEJBRemote.process(args[0]);       
   }
}
```

From my web app I invoke as below. Local method invocation is happened in this case

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DisplayInbound {
    @EJB
    private CoreMainEJBLocal coreMainEJBLocal;

    public void processPackages() {
        coreMainEJBLocal.process(...);   
    }
}
```

So here is my question, **If the EJB only exposed @Remote interface, but in your web app, you inject the EJB bean directly instead of its Remote interface, will this trigger a remote invocation or local invocation?** For example:

```
@Stateless
public class CoreMainEJB implements CoreMainEJBRemote{
    //...
}
```

and in the web app, I do this

```
@EJB
private CoreMainEJB coreMainEJB;

public void processPackages() {
    coreMainEJB.process(...);   //Is this local or remote invocation here?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last example as given will simply not work. Since `CoreMainEJB` already implements a remote interface, the container will **not** create a No-Interface view. This is exactly the case for which `@LocalBean` is intended.

So to answer the question '*Is this local or remote invocation here?*' directly: it's neither. The container will not be able to inject anything and probably barf out at the deployment stage.

If you define your bean as:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class CoreMainEJB implements CoreMainEJBRemote{
    //...
}
```

Then local semantics will apply here:

```
@EJB
private CoreMainEJB coreMainEJB;

public void processPackages() {
    coreMainEJB.process(...);   // Local semantics
}
```

*(assuming the above code fragment is in the same application as where `CoreMainEJB` is defined of course)*

Comment: Sorry. I was busy on another project so I reply a bit late. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

A no-interface invocation is a local invocation.

Comment: hehe.. this is what I want to hear. Thanks

Comment: This is actually why they added the `@LocalBean` annotation to EJB 3.1.

Comment: @TC1: If you look at my code, I did have not `@LocalBean` in my EJB, and that is the reason why I want to confirm whether this call is local or remote invocation.

Comment: @Harry Pham Afaik, `@LocalBean` is assumed as the default if you use the bean directly in a local context, as with a lot of things in JEE6, this is yet another example of configuration-by-exception. Notice, i.e., how you can specify `@EJB` on an interface and Java finds the implementation itself (if it's unambiguous). Don't really wanna delve into the JSR for a quote on the `@LocalBean` now though, and tbh I don't care enough to do so...

Comment: EJB 3.1 section 4.9.8: "If the bean does not expose any other client views (Local, Remote, No-Interface, 2.x Remote Home, 2.x Local Home, Web Service) and its implements clause is empty, the bean defines a no-interface view. [...] The following interfaces are excluded when determining whether the bean exposes a no-interface view : java.io.Serializable; java.io.Externalizable; any of the interfaces defined by the javax.ejb package."

Comment: >A no-interface invocation is a local invocation - true, but it actually doesn't answer the question about the code fragment since there's no no-interface view there.